# What information is lost when row reduction is applied to a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am taking my second course in Linear Algebra, and am having trouble understanding the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofLinearAlgebra.html), especially the relationship between the transpose, rowspace, and how row reduction preserves the span of the row space. Besides rank, what does row reduction preserve if it doesn't effect the kernel, row, and column space? Why is the transpose emphasized if it's a completely different matrix and isn't necessarily the inverse of the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When row reduction is applied to a matrix the following information will be lost.

1. The determinant may change.
2. The eigenvalues may change.
3. The eigenvectors may change.
4. The characteristic polynomial may change.
5. The dynamic system defined by the matrix may change.
6. The row space and column space may change.

That is not a complete list but gives you a hint about some of the lost information.